# PayPal IPN simulator testing produces an empty curl result. Works fine in live

Tags: php, curl, paypal, paypal-ipn, string

I'm feel a bit out of my depth here. I have been having an issue with the sandbox IPN simulator since this PayPal overhaul a few days back.

Basically the curl result usually says VERIFIED or INVALID and now seems to be returning an empty string.

This exact same code works in live mode but not for me now in sandbox:

```
$post_fields ='cmd=_notify-validate';

foreach($_POST as $key => $val)
{
  $post_fields .= "&$key=".urlencode($val);
}

$ch =  curl_init();
// $url is https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_fields);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

$ch_result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

I have had a good look around and tried various suggestions such as using HTTP version 1.1 and adding `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Connection: Close'));` and nothing seems to work.

I get all the other post fields ok it's just the $ch_result. Pretty stumped, has anyone else had this issue and were they able to resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

i have same issue using separate but related technology (html/os vs php) and ditto, getting blank var returned instead of "verified or invalid" and yet the same code works fine in live mode as i am still getting orders ...

i did read last night (saturday) this thread -> [IPN simulator returning 401 error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15302710/ipn-simulator-returning-401-error) ... which seems to suggest paypal developers are aware of issue ... to the extend they are aware, who knows as i sent two emails 36 hours ago and still nada but then again, tiz weekend so maybe on monday things will clear up .. .

also note ... that when i forced / faked an ipn call to bypass this bug, i did see that they seemed to have changed the var payment_status to a numeric of 2 vs previous "completed" ...

oye vey ... such are the pains of so called technology upgrades ... technically imho i think they should rename software to concreteware as once things are stable, leave the *it alone unless security ... all this nonsense about "improvements" - ugh - see Windows Vista, Windows 8.0 but i digress ... cordially, chuck scott

Comment: Welcome to SO. While your answer adds value to a possible discussion, it would be a better fit to a site with a forum format. Refer to http://stackoverflow.com/about to learn about the site and what ohter users expectations are.

Comment: Thank you Chuck, I'm glad it's not just me. I didn't even notice the payment_status value changes before. I guess the 'solution' really is to wait for PayPal then :) Nice.